# Extracting text from a class which has a child class

Tags: javascript, jquery

The structure is as follows

```
<li class="upper-class">
   <span class="hidden">unwanted-text</span>
   wanted-text
</li>
```

I have tried

```
$('.upper-class').not('.hidden').text();
```

and it returns

```
unwanted-text
 wanted-text
```

looking for a jquery solution
for it to only return

```
wanted-text
```

Edit:

Provided answers are not related to this situation. I want to use only parent class and I want text excluding the DIV having specific class.

Comment: You want to get text of `uppar-class` only when it  has a child class `hidden` ?

Comment: Maybe you should set the wanted text into some element with a given class, so that it can be selected easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First clone the element, remove the children. And then get the text from the element.

```js
console.log($('.upper-class').clone()
            .children()
            .remove('.hidden')
            .end()
            .text()
            .trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="upper-class">
   <span class="hidden">unwanted-text</span>
   wanted-text
</li>
```

Comment: Used this method, thank you

Comment: its quite inefficient but works fine...